# root url executes fine but not any other url of symfony2 project on shared hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, shared-hosting

I have a symfony project . I have deployed it on godaddy shared hosting .
The Dir structure is -

```
|- godaddy root
   |- site1
   |- site2
   |- symfony_project
```

I have pointed my symfony site url to symfony_project directory. So if my url is example.com , the page is rendered for the / route . So if I type example.com/web/ , the / route is executed . But any other url does not work , like example.com/web/link1 does not work .. I have tried various modifications of .htaccess , but none seems to work for me . 
Also if I go through godaddy root url , like godaddyroot.com/symfony_project/web/link1 , everything works fine . 
The 404 error says

The requested URL /symfony_project/symfony_project/web/app.php was not found on this server.
How to make this thing work .

Answer (score 2):

How I solved this

In the htaccess in the goddady root , write the following code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /symfony_project/web/$1
</IfModule>
```

Hope this might help someone ...